# Couldn't connect POP3 in mule esb

Tags: gmail, mule, mule-studio, pop3, mule-component

I am facing problem while receiving mail from gmail using POP3 connector..
I got Authentication error and socket EOF error..

```
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentStartException: AuthenticationFailedException: EOF on socket
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:155)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$4.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:98)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.start(ArtifactWrapper.java:93)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:26)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:310)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:330)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedApp(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:297)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:108)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployExplodedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:290)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:151)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:99)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:152)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15)
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to start inbound endpoint "endpoint.pop3.mailaddress.gmail.com"
    at org.mule.endpoint.DefaultInboundEndpoint.start(DefaultInboundEndpoint.java:118)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.startIfStartable(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:322)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.doStart(AbstractPipeline.java:315)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$2.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:141)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$2.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:137)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:138)
    at org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireStartPhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:92)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.start(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:136)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:237)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager$RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:273)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:152)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:123)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:76)
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:136)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:91)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:87)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:69)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:61)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:278)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:133)
    ... 13 more
```

And my flow is..

```
<pop3:connector checkFrequency="100" doc:name="POP3" name="POP3" validateConnections="true" />

<flow name="incoming-orders" doc:name="incoming-orders">


        <pop3:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="POP3" doc:name="POP3" host="pop.gmail.com" password="pwd" port="995" responseTimeout="1000" user="mail%40gmail.com"/>

        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

</flow>
```

I want to receive my mail...I could't connect to gmail..My pwd and username are correct still I got authentication error. 
In my gmail account POP3 is enabled..
How can I solve this issue????

Answer (score 0):

i was watching your comment and i had the same problem, just worked once, but later change my pop3s configuration like this, and it worked, i hope and works for you too.

```
<pop3s:connector name="pop3sConnector" checkFrequency="30000" doc:name="POP3" validateConnections="true">
    <pop3s:tls-client path="*" storePassword="*"/>
    <pop3s:tls-trust-store path="*" storePassword="*"/>
</pop3s:connector>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the '@gmail.com' part of the user attribute.

Comment: Then there is another problem but if you check the logs when the connection is trying to get established you'll see that the "@" is added implicitly, so the user should not have it. About the other issue, 2 things come to mind: 1) enabling POP and less secure apps in the gmail account and 2) that gmail requires you to use SSL.

Comment: Actually, I don't have enough reputation to comment below posts, I've tried and apparently you need over 50 reputation. Besides, the @ thing is a problem in the provided config that would cause such an app to fail. Thanks though, I look forward to crossing that 50 rep barrier so I can comment everywhere and help out in a proper way.

Comment: @user3855589 just tried this in 3.6.0 and it worked ```<pop3s:inbound-endpoint host="pop.gmail.com" port="995" user="mail" password="pwd" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="POP3"/>```. Notice the ```pop3s``` and the ```mail``` changes. I hope it helps.

Comment: Do you get an exception or the mail is just not being processed? I believe only unread mail is processed so if you run the app and after processing the mail is marked as read the app won't pick them up a second time.

Comment: Is it possible. Every time I got read as well as unread both mail?